# How to speak mathematics

Tags: vocabulary, expressions

I've been asked to give lectures on electromagnetism in English, but I encounter many problems trying to express mathematical formulas since they are written and I do not know how to read them. Are there any references which elaborate the formulas and express what should we call any mathematical sign?

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call this off-topic, but I think you might be able to get better answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/, although I'm not sure they would find it on topic.

Comment: I think they might hate it.

Comment: Perhaps asking in the mathematics chat would be best, plenty of them will have been to and given mathematics lectures: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: I've voted to reopen and asked a [question on meta.math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/is-this-question-on-topic-on-mathematics-se) whether this kind of questions is on-topic there.

Comment: Can the people who closed this give a justification? This is a question about pronunciation that one cannot find in dictionaries.

Comment: I agree with you Phira

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following references are useful:

- [Pronunciation Guides for Mathematical Notation, Expressions, and Greek Letters (*Reference list*)](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/05/pronunciation-guides-for-mathematical.html)
- [Reading Mathematical Expressions (*PDF*)](http://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/link/Mathe-pronun.pdf)
- [How can we speak math? (*PDF*)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/speakmath.pdf)

Comment: @Negin: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Also: mathematicians are used to international speakers, and will understand things said in different ways.  It won't matter if you read "x/2" as "x over 2" or "x upon 2", they have probably heard them both before.  Or if Z is called "zee" or "zed".  Now if Y is called "eegrek" they may smile...

Answer (score 2):

There's a certain amount of variation in how signs are denoted in speech, not least that given signs may have a different meaning in context (simple example: a superscripted number is usually a power, but it might not be).

You're best asking a colleague who is a mathematician who was educated at, or has a long association, with the institution where you will be lecturing, and knows the standard conventions there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about this, I am afraid you are likely to bore your audience to tears. Describing mathematical equations orally is rarely effective. You would be much better off to provide a hand-out with a numbered list of all equations you wish to discuss, and refer to them by number.

Comment: Please don't do this! My guess is, James has never attended a math talk for and by mathematicians :)

Comment: Actually... oh, heck, just check out the bio on my profile.